# Private Activity (Fragments, etc) in Android Library

Tags: android, android-library

I need create my own "SDK" for consume some features of my API... But, for security reasons, I need create a "private flow" (Activity, Layout, etc) to guarantee users privacy (users can put CreditCard info, etc)... It's possible create a private Activity (Fragments, etc) in Android Library?

Comment: What do you mean by Private Activity?

Comment: Thinking about request user CreditCard number... Other devs (using my SDK) don't see my CreditCardActivity and can't see my secret flow, blocking "spy" implementations, for example...